# Best practices for inheritance structure of a Maven Project with modules

Tags: java, maven

I'm try to figuring out with the best way to define inheritance structure for a Maven Project organized in modules.
Let me introduce the scenario.

I'm developing a Web Application which can be extended for different customer.
Each personalization contains custom GUI components, data warehouse logic, etc..

I create the primary **pom.xml**, defined as *packaging*, which rappresent the main project container and includes shared dependencies and modules definition:

- *Core Library* Module: artifactID: **cms-core**
- *Base Web Application* GUI Module artifcatId: **cms-base-app**
- Customer 1 Web Application Module
- ...
- Customer N Web Application Module

Pom.xml has defined as following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>it.isipc</groupId>
  <artifactId>cms-env</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>cms.env</name>
  <description>...</description>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>
  <build>
    ...
  </build>
  <dependencies>
        ...
  </dependencies>
  
  <modules>
    <module>cms-core</module>
    <module>cms-base-app</module>
    ...
    <module>cms-customer1</module>
    ...
  </modules>
</project>
```

Basically, I usually make changes at Core Library and Base application module.
Everytime I release a new version on any of those modules, I need to update pom.xml of each customer's module in order to update them at the last released version of mentioned artifacts.
Following an example of a customer web application **pom.xml**:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>it.isipc</groupId>
    <artifactId>cms-env</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.0</version>
  </parent>
  <version>1.11.05</version>
  <artifactId>cms-customer1</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>cms-customer1/name>
  <description>...</description>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>it.isipc</groupId>
        <artifactId>cms-base-app</artifactId>
        <type>war</type>
        <version>1.11.05</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>it.isipc</groupId>
        <artifactId>cms-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

---

At the moment I have to specify:

1. Customer module's version (1.11.05 in the example above)
2. cms-base-app module's verion (1.11.05 in the example above)

Those two artifacts, in my idea, has to share the same version number because Customer Application extends Base Web Application.

Everything works fine as expected but I'm sure there's a best way for doing that.

There's a way to specify version number only on cms-base-app pom.xml file and make each customer's module inherit from that?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: In the example you give, there are many versions: `cms-env:0.0.0`, `cms-base-app:1.11.05`, `cms-core:1.1.3`, `cms-customer1:1.11.05`.
I think all the "root" modules (env, core, base-app) should have the same version. But each customer module should be able evolve its own way (new functionalities, bug fixes, ...).
Even if `customer` "extends" `cms-env`, it can have its own version.
So, do you think one version for "root" modules and one version per customer module is ok, or do you prefer one single version for all ?

Comment: Hi @Tigger thanks for your answer. I'm agree: each customer module has its own way to evolve. I think one version for "root" modules and one version per customer module can be the best solution. The main problem I'm facing with is that each time I update one of "root" modules I have to manually update reference in each customer moduls. I'm trying to find a simple/automatic way for doing that

Comment: First why are you using a war as a dependency? Second best would be to have dependencyManagement in parent for general dependencies. Third why having different versions for different modules? A multi module is intended to have the same versions for all modules...

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm using war as dependancy because I'm including old script which aren't deployed on a Maven repository (of course I can improve this management, just need more time). I already manage general dependencies in the "root" modules in 'cms-env' pom.xml (I omitted them in the example). In your opinion, if i change version for a customer compontents/logic, I should change version for all modules? I don't think this is a better solution... I suppose only general dependencies and commons libraries must share version number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible configuration if the need is:

- one version for all "root" modules
- one version per "customer" module

#### 1. Root modules

cms-env

```
<groupId>it.isipc</groupId>
<artifactId>cms-env</artifactId>
<version>0.0.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>cms-core</module>
    <module>cms-base-app</module>
    <module>cms-customer1</module>
</modules>
```

cms-core

```
<artifactId>cms-core</artifactId>
<parent>
    <groupId>it.isipc</groupId>
    <artifactId>cms-env</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.0</version>
</parent>
```

cms-base-app

```
<artifactId>cms-base-app</artifactId>
<parent>
    <groupId>it.isipc</groupId>
    <artifactId>cms-env</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.0</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>cms-core</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In children poms (`core` and `base-app`), no need to specify groupId nor version, it's inherited.

#### 2. Customer modules

```
<artifactId>cms-customer1</artifactId>
<version>1.2.3</version>
<parent>
    <groupId>it.isipc</groupId>
    <artifactId>cms-env</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.0</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>cms-base-app</artifactId>
        <version>${parent.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If `cms-base-app` has a dependency to `cms-core` (as set in part 1), no need to add it here, in customer module.

#### 3. Life cycle

When `customer1` evolves, just edit its pom (change the version).
When a "root" module changes, all poms have to be updated.
To do so, go to the `cms-env` directory, and then:
`mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=0.0.1`
If everything's fine, you can validate changes with:
`mvn versions:commit`
Otherwise, you can get back to previous poms with:
`mvn versions:rollback`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I take some time to test it. I answer you in a few days

Comment: I tried your solution and it works. Basically, 'cms-core' and 'cms-base-app' share main project version number and each customer implementation follows its own way of versioning. Maybe, be able to control each core artifact version could be better but, in this environment, both core artifacts rappresent main project. Sharing same version number it's a small price to pay. I mark your answear as accepted answear .Thanks for your help, cheers.